# Retrieving ERROR and WARNING messages from SWI-Prolog through JPL

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I am having some trouble retrieving error and warning messages when using JPL.
For example, attempting to consult a non-existing file directly from SWI-Prolog produces the following output:

```
1 ?- consult('NonExistingFile').
ERROR: source_sink `NonExistingFile' does not exist
true.
```

However, when executing this query through JPL, no exception is thrown and the hasMoreSolutions() method of the Query class returns true:

```
Query query = new Query("consult('NonExistingFile')");
query.hasMoreSolutions();
```

How can I detect that an error has occurred and consulting NonExistingFile.pl has actually failed? The same question applies to retrieving warning messages that don't cause the predicate execution to fail.

**Edit: the described situation occurs when using JPL with SWI-Prolog versions up to 6.0.2**

Comment: I tried, but I got the exception:`Exception in thread "main" jpl.PrologException: PrologException: error(existence_error(source_sink, 'NonExistingFile'), _0)
 at jpl.Query.get1(Query.java:336)
 at jpl.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:258)
 at Exceptions.main(Exceptions.java:13)`

Comment: That is very interesting. I'm only getting this error message in the default error stream (System.err): "ERROR: source_sink `NonExistingFile' does not exist". But no exception is thrown. What versions of SWI-Prolog/JPL are you using?

Comment: I try to keep just the latest. I'm running Linux and I always build from source with default setting. Jan released 2 or 3 days ago an update, I have still to upgrade...When I run `~/pl-devel/packages/jpl/examples/java/Versions$ ./run.sh` I get `JPL demo: Versions

% /home/carlo/.plrc compiled 0.00 sec, 8 clauses
prolog library version; 3.1.4-alpha
  java library version; 3.1.4-alpha
     c library version; 3.1.4-alpha
BINGO! you appear to have the same version of each library installed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem regarding consulting errors is resolved when using JPL with SWI-Prolog 6.1.9 (currently the development version). An exception is thrown when attempting to consult a file that does not exist.